# Not sure why I'm failing test cases?

Tags: function, python-3.x, parameters, conditional-statements

I'm building a function that replaces a limited number of old values with new values in a list (xs) and returns the replaced numbers as a new list (new_xs). I am failing most test cases. I have provided two examples of expected output and two examples of failing test cases.

Example:

> Limit= None (means replace all old values) xs=[1,2,1,3,1,4,1,5,1] old= 1 new=2 --> new_xs[2,2,2,3,2,4,2,5,2]
>
> Limit= 0 or negative means do not alter anything in the list
>
> Limit=2 means only replace two old values and leave rest untouched.

Here is my non-working code:

```
def replace(xs, old, new, limit=None):
    new_xs=[]
    replacements=0
    for num in xs:
        if num == old and (limit is None or replacements<limit):
            new_xs.append(new)
            replacements+=1
        else:
            new_xs.append(num)
    return new_xs
```

Still fails 6 tests:

AssertionError: [] != None

AssertionError: Lists differ: [9, 2, 9, 3, 9, 4, 9, 5, 9] != [-10, 2, -10, 3, -10, 4, -10, 5, -10]

Comment: Could it be that you want an `elif` on line 9 instead of an `if`?

Comment: `elif` is shorthand syntax for nesting an `if` in an `else`.

Comment: The issue that you're encountering is that when `limit == None`, it's still compared to 0, so yes.

Comment: you can't use inequality operators with `None`. Just use `if num == old and (limit is None or replacements<limit):`. Because python reads the arguments to logical operators from left to right, if the first argument in an `or` is `True` or the first argument in an `and` is `False`, it never evaluates the second argument so the error won't be encountered.

Comment: Okay so I did as you said but I'm still failing 6/9 test cases. I included two examples of failing outputs. Can you see what's going on?

Comment: What is your input?

Comment: @Unlocked input for second example of failure is xs = [9,2,9,3,9,4,9,5,9]
  replace(xs,9,-10,5)

Comment: It works fine for me. What's the issue?

Comment: @Unlocked the issue is this failing test case: AssertionError: Lists differ: [9, 2, 9, 9, 9, 5, 4, 3, 2, 9] != [-10, 2, -10, -10, -10, 5, 4, 3, 2, -10]

Comment: What is giving you that output? That doesn't seem like any kind of standard python error.